# Asset Duplication in AssetForge

Tags: architecture, assets

Is it possible to duplicate assets in AssetForge? For instance, if I build a house and want to duplicate the entire house to another spot with it.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I looked in the menu and tried right clicking and clicking and dragging. There must be a way as that is usually a standard feature with this type of software.